# Multiline query execution

Tags: c#, sql

I am the Lead Developer on a web-based corporate tax payment application written in C#.

My boss asked to develop a script to get him some relevant data from our application.

Now he's asked me to port it to a Desktop Application so he can run the script himself and not have to ask me for the report every time he needs it.

The database is hosted by Azure and one of the restrictions it has is there can be no Stored Procedures.

My problem is that the query written to generate the report is rather complex, requiring a few variable declarations as well as multiple while loops.

The issue I'm having is how can I run the entire script as a single query without access to Stored Procedures? Is it even possible?

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(unificadoCommand, connection))
            {
                var s = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (s.Read())
                {
                    //Process data
                }
            }
        }
```

I expected to get the results of the query with data about the payments in the website but it fails with a timeout exception on command.ExecuteReader()

EDIT: Someone asked for the query. Whilst I can't post the query here as it's protected data from my company, I can explain how I built it.

Basically, I first DECLARE 4 INTs and my output table. Next, I have three while loops set up in a way that I INSERT into my output table the data I SELECT from the actual tables.

At the end of the while loops, I simply SELECT * FROM OutputTable.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the query.

Comment: Rather than install Net Library  on bosses PC or publish the application maybe the better solution is install SQL Server Management Studio on bosses PC.  Then you can use the command line utility sqlcmd.exe which you can setup a .bat file and output data to csv.  Then boss can open the csv in excel.  sqlcmd.exe accept a command text which can use stored procedure.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15   The sqlcmd.exe commands are built into a Power Shell so you can write a power shell script.

Comment: How about you add a website to your web-application that may only be accessed by a certain role your boss has. on this site, you can call that query and present it in a readable way. That way you can use your familiar c# tools inside your web-app with already registered credentials. *All other solutions would require you to give away the credentials, thus being insecure.*

Comment: The timeout is suspicious, it might be useful to try and get that solved first. Without the query and being able to reproduce we are not able to help

Comment: Generally, you should not have any issues executing multi-line queries within a single ExecuteReader or Execute call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Erno suggested the timeout was suspicious and @500 - Internal Server Error said there should be no problems running multi-line queries, I did some research and found that after setting the command timeout to at least 100 seconds, the query runs perfectly.

Thanks so much everyone who helped me out.